# accdb vs mdb access database file

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

what is the difference between these two extensions?

i need to write to an access database from a WORD file using an ADODB connection

when i create a new access database it gives me the option to make only an ACCDB file and for some reason i cannot make an MDB file

can someone please help me create an MDB file so that i am able to make an ADODB connection to it in order to write to the database/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [this explanation](http://databases.about.com/od/access/a/accdb.htm).

Also, in Access, 'save as' will give you older versions to save as (including .mdb).

(from above link) 
by using the ACCDB format, you will be able to:

- Include attachments in your database. (supports BLOBs)
- Use multivalued fields. (store "check all that apply" in one field)
- Safe integration with SharePoint and Outlook (you can e-mail accdb and Outlook won't block them)
- Encryption improvements

ACCDB databases do not support user level security or replication.